# Python elasticutils http authentication or api key?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, http-authentication, elasticutils

Hello I'm currently using elasticutils in django to search indexed documents but my cluster doesn't have any authentication method so anyone can access to my ES server from internet, is there any way to set a key o auth method with elasticutils in order to the only servers with the key can query to the ES server?

Something likely searchly or amazon keys api's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of protecting your ES cluster.

The easiest way would be to install a plugin such as [elasticsearch-http-basic](https://github.com/Asquera/elasticsearch-http-basic) in order to protect your cluster. You can configure it with a [BASIC username/password](https://github.com/Asquera/elasticsearch-http-basic#configuration) combo and then it's just a matter of configuring [elasticutils](https://github.com/mozilla/elasticutils) to pass those BASIC credentials along to the underlying ES client provided by the [elasticsearch-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) library.

When calling `get_es(...)` you simply need to add the `http_auth` parameter which will be passed along to the `Elasticsearch` constructor like this:

```
es_client = get_es(urls=['localhost:9200'], http_auth="username:password")
```

Another way is to hide your ES cluster behind a web server like Apache or Nginx, but it's more involved than the above solution.

You can also use [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield), just know it is a commercial product.

Comment: Thanks a lot @val, yes it works perfectly although I installed the shield plugin in my es_server, the auth-method (es_client = get_es(urls=['localhost:9200'], http_auth="username:password"))you suggested me works fine  with shield. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/enable-basic-auth.html